# Set global handling for PHP scripts in NGINX + PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, php5, php-fpm

I have to define fastcgi_pass for every virtual host. How do I define it global-wise?

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.tld;

    location / {
        root   /home/user/www.domain.tld;
        index  index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/user/domain.tld$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Anyways, I switched back to Apache. Nginx is not a webserver - it's proxy server. =))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a file that you can `include` wherever you need it. For instance:

```
cat > /etc/nginx/php-fpm <<EOF
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include        fastcgi_params;
EOF
```

Then modify your `location` to `include php-fpm;` and fix the `root` directive (it should appear under `server`, not under `location /`; this is a [common nginx misconfiguration](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)).

Comment: How do I customize `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/user/domain.tld$fastcgi_script_name;` so it's not the same for every site? Also `root` specified under location in default `nginx.conf-dist`

Comment: Oops, I forgot that part. See the edited answer.

Comment: Hi, Do you know if there is an option/variable for the `fastcgi_pass` directive to define different unix domain sockets i.e.: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;` would be something like: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/$fastcgi_socket;`?
`

Comment: @HTF You should ask your own question.