# Nginx variable for fastcgi_pass

Tags: nginx

I came across this [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/440567/set-global-handling-for-php-scripts-in-nginx-php-fpm) topic and I'm wondering if there is an option/variable for the `fastcgi_pass` directive to define different unix domain sockets i.e.: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;` would be something like: `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/$fastcgi_socket;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no pre-existing variable, no. But you can use whatever socket you need to use, so long as the socket file exists, and php-fpm is configured to use it.